# Firebase Rules: make one of the fields private while allowing to read the rest

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in my firebase database:

```
{
    rooms: {
        roomId$: {
            users: {...},
            name: "Room Name",
            password: "abc123",
            owner: "ownerId"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to allow reading for every field except for password. 
So, I created the following rules:

```
"rooms": {
  "$roomId": {
    "name": {
      ".read": "true"
    },
    "users": {
      ".read": "true"
    },
    "owner": {
      ".read": "true"
    },
    "password": {
      ".read": "data.parent().child('owner').val() === auth.uid",
      ".write": "data.parent().child('owner').val() === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

The question is - is it possible to read all the room info at once at the `$roomId` level, while hiding the `password` field? Or nesting public and private fields separately is the only way?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the private data for a room into a different "branch" in the JSON tree, something like this:

```
{
    rooms: {
        roomId$: {
            users: {...},
            name: "Room Name",
            owner: "ownerId"
        }
    }
    roomsprivateinfo: {
        roomId$: {
            owner: "ownerId",
            password: "abc123"
        }
    }
}
```

This approach lets you write one rule for the "rooms" branch that allows public access and then write a separate rule for the "roomsprivateinfo" branch that limits access.  The owner is stored in both trees to make the rules easier to write.

This approach also does not require you to write a new rule every time you add a new field with information about a room.